# (pdf)latex doesn't recognize some Postscript fonts

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I'm running this *MWE* in *MiKTeX 2.9* on Windows 7 Professional Operative System

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{manfnt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\manerrarrow
\end{document}
```

The trouble is

- If i run it with `latex`, `pdflatex` or `lualatex` i get a *pixelated* font created from `manfnt.pk` as is explained in the `.log`. Here a part of the read fonts:

  > ```
  > {
  > C:/Program Files/LaTeX/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc} <C:
  > \Users\LuisP\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\public\misc\dpi600\manfnt.pk>
  > <C:/Program Files/LaTeX/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>
  > ```

  I have installed the packages `cm-super` (Adobe Type 1 fonts to replace Computer Modern fonts) and `hoekwater` (Fonts originally created in MetaFont, transformed to PostScript by Taco Hoekwater; includes logo, manfnt, rsfs, stmaryrd, wasy, wasy2, xipa).

  Although `hoekwater` includes `manfnt.pfb`, this is not read and the result is the ugly
  [image]
- However if i run it with `xelatex` then there no problem and the result is the expected 
  [image]

Is there someone capable to explain me this *issue*?

Comment: The code is fine. MiKTeX does not always update the font stuff correctly but I don't know much about it. I know you need to run `updmap` or the equivalent of doing that to update the map files. (XeTeX probably doesn't rely on the map files whereas pdfTeX does.)

Comment: It is an error in the miktex package. The map-file is missing. I will make a bug report. In the mean time as a work-around download the map file http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mflogo/ps-type1/hoekwater/mflogo.map (make sure that you get a map file and not a html-file!) but it in your document folder and add \pdfmapfile{+mflogo.map}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it seems to be a *frequent* problem of *MiKTeX*. This problem appears also with the *fonts* of the package `cmll` and the solution is similar: Add `Map cmll.map` (`cmll.map` is already included in the `cmll` package) to `updmap.cfg` and run `updmap`.

Comment: Yes it happens that a map is missing. It is also a *frequent* problem that people don't make suitable bug reports.

Comment: The miktex bug has been resolved. You should install the new mflogo-font package (and perhaps run updmap).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `manfnt.map` is missing from the MiKTeX distribution, hence the type 1 fonts are not mentioned in `dvips.map` and friends.

What you can do:

1. Create manfnt.map, copying these two lines

   ```
   % Thomas Esser, 1998, public domain.
   manfnt manfnt <manfnt.pfb
   ```

Place in a `LocalTeXMF`  (if you don't have one, create one and add it to the list of TeX roots via `MiKTeX Settings`, `Roots` tab. More precisely, put it in `…\LocalTeXMF\fonts\map\dvips\manfnt`.

2. Go to `C:\Users\Your_Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config` and open your personal `updmap.cfg` file. If you don't have one, create it, and insert these lines:

   ```
   # Manfnt

   Map manfnt.map
   ```

Save the file and refresh the FNBD. Never write in the distribution `updmap.cfg`, as it will be overwritten on updates.

3. As administrator run from the command line: `updmap --verbose`. The switch wlil display what's happening.

It then should work:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but i'd like that it was fixed from *MiKTeX*.